# audio volume low after installing new motherboard

Tags: audio

I installed a new motherboard very recently. Everything is working fine, but the sound volume has become very low. the volume is not very high even after setting full volume. what should i do?

Comment: What hardware? What OS?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the latest drivers for your motherboard's onboard audio are installed.

Ensure that the sound settings in the Windows Sound Mixer (if you're using Windows) are set to 100% volume. You could also try [this fix](http://www.ehow.com/how_5820564_fix-windows-low-volume-problem.html) if you're running Windows 7.

It is possible that your motherboard's onboard audio puts out less power than your previous motherboard's. You could always purchase another sound card or an external amplifier to increase output power.